# htaccess Rewrite GET variables in URL, but still have access to them

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to put something in my .htaccess file that will allow me to change the following URL:

```
http://www.mysite.com/profile?user=theuser
```

To something like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/profile/theuser
```

But in the page, still be able to do something like:

```
echo $_GET['user']; // echos "theuser"
```

Is this possible? How would I do this?

NOTE: I am trying to get the URL in the address bar to show `http://www.mysite.com/profile/theuser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(profile)/(theuser)/?$ $1?user=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is how URL rewriting works by design.

The URL is rewritten internally into the

```
http://www.mysite.com/profile?user=theuser
```

format.

Comment: This is not actually how mod_rewrite works. By default it discards the query string (see the link in my answer).

Comment: The OP just wants a normal rewrite.

Comment: He wants a normal rewrite, but he wants the query string to be passed along to the new url, which makes it not a normal rewrite.

Comment: @Paul nope, read the question again. He is asking whether GET variables still work when he uses a RewriteRule.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to rewrite the URL and still use the GET variables, but I don't know the formatting of the rewrite rule. Ive tried as many other examples as I can find on this site and I cant seem to get any of them to work.

Comment: I see. I read it as he wants to rewrite `http://www.mysite.com/profile?user=theuser` to `http://www.mysite.com/profile/theuser?user=theuser` internally, but I think he just worded it wrong.