# htaccess Rewrite rule to send variable info to script but display clean url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

What I'd like to do is when a URL like

```
http://localhost/sandbox/jcsearch/country/countryname
```

is typed by the user I would like to to point to

```
http://localhost/sandbox/jcsearch/index.php?country=countryname
```

but still retain the original clean URL in the address bar ie

```
http://localhost/sandbox/jcsearch/country/countryname
```

Is this possible? would it create any kind of redirect loop?

Comment: Yes, it is possible look up `pretty URLs`. It shouldn't loop unless done incorrectly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [htaccess Rewrite GET variables in URL, but still have access to them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954894/htaccess-rewrite-get-variables-in-url-but-still-have-access-to-them)

Comment: If you use htaccess rewrite then it will always show your original URL in the address bar.

Comment: @chris85 I'm not sure its a duplicate of that post. I'm looking for the user to enter the pretty url but for htaccess to deliver the variable to the script without changing how the URL is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rewrite would happen as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^sandbox/jcsearch/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ sandbox/jcsearch/index.php?$1=$2 [L,NC]
```

Since, the `RewriteRule` directive does not have the redirection flag (`R`) set, it will not change the URL in your browser's addressbar. So, by visiting

```
http://localhost/sandbox/jcsearch/country/countryname
```

user will get internally redirected to:

```
http://localhost/sandbox/jcsearch/index.php?country=countryname
```

**Please note**: You have to put the rewrite rules in the htaccess file in your server root directory.

Comment: Exactly what was needed. Thank you! The resulting page doesnt show the css though but I think I'll fix that.

Comment: @RonaldFernandes Read about and use `RewriteBase` in the htaccess above and the `<base>` element in HTML

Comment: Yes. That was what I did. I tried the rewrite base but it threw an error so I just went with the HTML `<base>`

Comment: I also modified the Rewrite Rule to only do the redirect only when the /country/ is specified.
`RewriteRule ^sandbox/jcsearch/(country)/([^/]+)$ sandbox/jcsearch/index.php?$1=$2 [L,NC]`